# Com editar a TabControl em c#?

Tags: c#

Pretendo ocultar apenas a parte da `TabControl` que vem o nome da tabpagina em C#, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível?

Answer (score 3):

Se você não quer que as abas apareçam, muito provavelmente está usando o componente errado.

O `TabControl` serve exatamente para disponibilizar abas.

Ao invés de `TabControl`, considere utilizar um `Panel`. Você pode encontrar a documentação da classe `Panel` [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais fácil, e que pode ser feita pelas propriedades do controle é a seguinte:

```
tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

Se isso não resolver seu problema aí você terá que criar um controle personalizado. Adicione uma classe ao seu projeto com o seguinte código:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TablessControl : TabControl {
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode) m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    else base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Compile o projeto. No topo da toolbar deve aparecer um novo controle. Arraste ele para a tela e use normalmente como o TabControl padrão. Ao executar o aplicativo as abas não serão criadas